# What are the list of nodes at the bottom of kovan.json?

Tags: genesis, kovan, enode

The [Genesis file for Kovan](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/blob/master/ethcore/res/ethereum/kovan.json) has a list of nodes at the bottom. What are these nodes for? Is this just a list of known Kovan nodes?

```
"nodes": [
    "enode://56abaf065581a5985b8c5f4f88bd202526482761ba10be9bfdcd14846dd01f652ec33fde0f8c0fd1db19b59a4c04465681fcef50e11380ca88d25996191c52de@40.71.221.215:30303",
    "enode://d07827483dc47b368eaf88454fb04b41b7452cf454e194e2bd4c14f98a3278fed5d819dbecd0d010407fc7688d941ee1e58d4f9c6354d3da3be92f55c17d7ce3@52.166.117.77:30303",
    "enode://38e6e7fd416293ed120d567a2675fe078c0205ab0671abf16982ce969823bd1f3443d590c18b321dfae7dcbe1f6ba98ef8702f255c3c9822a188abb82c53adca@51.77.66.187:30303",
    "enode://6f289111f7c77c68651b0f4803c3a47bcec801f9c618bb41231a1a24a6dbb9c76f2fdb63ba7a21357c41ebb7f6922c17397c1b5c8f71f7d3ef7965505d4945de@144.217.72.209:30303",
    "enode://b6340eb94c3db1362ee517801389fe21cce6354275376b1006f8ce84f8a5cfa2b836268b3727be9db7cd3e581f356f39da39418c4ec1d63d959abc235d99cd86@145.239.7.213:30303"  
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [`spec.rs`](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/blob/6dfc1bd4749e7e77ebeabbc32655787855637401/json/src/spec/spec.rs#L40), the `nodes` key contains hard-coded boot node values:

```
/// Spec deserialization.
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Deserialize)]
#[serde(deny_unknown_fields)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct Spec {
    /// Spec name.
    pub name: String,
    /// Special fork name.
    pub data_dir: Option<String>,
    /// Engine.
    pub engine: Engine,
    /// Spec params.
    pub params: Params,
    /// Genesis header.
    pub genesis: Genesis,
    /// Genesis state.
    pub accounts: State,
    /// Boot nodes.
    pub nodes: Option<Vec<String>>,                     <------
    /// Hardcoded synchronization for the light client.
    pub hardcoded_sync: Option<HardcodedSync>,
}
```